# Modal Popup from the InfoPath 2010 Browser Enabled Form

Tags: 2010, infopath

I need to open a popup window to display help messages (Large text) related to fields in the infopath form.

I have developed a application page to display the popup messages on click event of a hyperlink, but I don't have an option to resize the window.

Is there a way to call the javascript from the Infopath forms?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ramesh.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use the [XmlFormView control](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms772268%28v=office.15%29) to host a browser-enabled form template in a webpart of a custom ASPX page and indirectly execute JScript code from the form template.

In an event handler of the Infopath XSN form template, use the [NotifyHost method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/aa946030%28v=office.14%29) of the XmlForm class.
In the ASPX webpage, hook up the [NotifyHost event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ms772252%28v=office.15%29) of the XmlFormView control to an event handler.
Register and execute JScript code from within the event handler in the ASPX page.

For more details check 5-part MSDN blog:

- [Open a SharePoint Modal Dialog from an InfoPath Form: Part 1 of 5 (Vivek Soni)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151102040429/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/17/open-a-sharepoint-modal-dialog-from-an-infopath-form-part-1-of-5.aspx)
- [Open a SharePoint Modal Dialog from an InfoPath Form: Part 2 of 5 (Vivek Soni)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151101021852/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/17/open-a-sharepoint-modal-dialog-from-an-infopath-form-part-2-of-5.aspx)
- [Open a SharePoint Modal Dialog from an InfoPath Form: Part 3 of 5 (Vivek Soni)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151101023701/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/18/open-a-sharepoint-modal-dialog-from-an-infopath-form-part-3-of-5.aspx)
- [Open a SharePoint Modal Dialog from an InfoPath Form: Part 4 of 5 (Vivek Soni)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151030051218/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/20/open-a-sharepoint-modal-dialog-from-an-infopath-form-part-4-of-5.aspx)
- [Open a SharePoint Modal Dialog from an InfoPath Form: Part 5 of 5 (Vivek Soni)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151120234845/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/21/open-a-sharepoint-modal-dialog-from-an-infopath-form-part-5-of-5.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did check that solution, it requires another aspx page to host the inforpath form. If it is single infopath form we can host in the aspx but I need to store all the forms in the Form Library and users can edit the individual forms.

Comment: I believe I have answered your question. If you have another one, please post is as a separate question. If it is not single Infopath form, they still can be hosted as multiple Infopath Web Parts in ASPX Web Part page or as content types into the form library. The same is valid for a single Infopath form. I do not see any difference, though it is completely different question which is BTW is not even formulated